# Как сделать что бы при наведении на слайд слайдер прокручивался? Слайдер сделан с помощью slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider-slick.js

```
$('.main__blog-items').slick({
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить событие 'mouseenter' для слайдов и вызвать функцию lickNext() внутри этого события

```
$('.main__blog-items').on('init', function(event, slick){
  slick.$slides.addClass('slick-slide');
}).slick({
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
    draggable: true
});
$('.main__blog-items').on('mouseenter', '.slick-slide' function(){
    $('.main__blog-items').slick('slickNext');
});
```

Это добавит событие наведения мыши на каждый слайд и прокрутит слайдер на один слайд вперед при наведении на любой из них.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Comment: А можешь еще подсказать как добавить класс для баковых слайдов и что бы при наведении на боковые слайды слайд прокручивался

Comment: событие init  добавит класс slick-slide на все слайды слайдера. `$('.main__blog-items').on('init',function(event, slick){slick.$slides.addClass('slick-slide');});` Важно иметь в виду, что событие init должно быть добавлено перед инициализацией слайдера Slick. В вашем случае вам нужно добавить следующий код перед $('.main__blog-items').slick({ ... });

Comment: Добавил в код. Посмотрите возможно вы так хотели. Не совсем понял ваш вопрос